# How to generate auto increment id manually using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, auto-increment

I am new in [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/). Without using auto increment in database i want to generate auto increment manually like `A00001, A00002, A00003 .......`

How can i generate this type of ID using codeigniter and mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, automatic auto increment is better for a primary key. But if you want to generate it, you can do it like this

```
function GenerateId() {
    $query = $this->db->select('ID')
                      ->from('table_name')
                      ->get();
    $row = $query->last_row();
    if($row){
        $idPostfix = (int)substr($row->ID,1)+1;
        $nextId = 'A'.STR_PAD((string)$idPostfix,5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    else{$nextId = 'A00001';} // For the first time
    return $nextId;
}
```